# Are Ito integrals equivalence classes or conrete random variables?

Tags: stochastic-processes, lp-spaces, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

Technically speaking, are Ito integrals of stochastic processes $S$ with respect to Brownian motion $B$

$$ \int_{0}^{T} S_s dB_s $$

random variables or equivalence classes of almost surely equal random variables?

Comment: I recall in David William’s *Probability with Martingales* he firmly states “There, [in the context of stochastic processes with uncountable parameter sets], the equivalence-class formulation just will not work; the “cleverness” of introducing quotient spaces loses the subtlety which is essential even for formulating the fundamental results on existence of continuous modifications, etc, ...” and I recall another book emphasizing how sample-path properties require focusing on functions rather than equivalence classes.

Comment: In the book "Brownian Motion, Martingales and Stochastic Calculus" by Le Gall, however, Ito integrals seem to be seen as unique processes only up to indistinguishability.

Comment: I guess this depends on a formulation. One can use classes or particularly "nice" representatives. It is the same with the ordinary Lebesgue spaces. One can use classes up to almost everywhere, or always take representatives that are equal to the limits of their averages at each Lebesgue point.